# Triple mustache to escape value erroring in Angular app

Tags: html, angular, typescript, handlebars.js, mustache

I've tried this in several different angular apps and get the same error. I've verified that the latest version of Handlebars is installed. Whenever I try to use the triple mustache `{{{` `}}}` to render html as html within an html file, the compiler throws this error (I'm using VSCode, but the same error occurs within the stackblitz below):

```
Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected : at the end of the expression [{{{item}}}] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@9:37 ("DropListEnterPredicate]="enter" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop()">
<div cdkDrag class="example-box">[ERROR ->]{{{item}}}</div>
</div>
</div> "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@9:37
Parser Error: Unexpected end of expression: {{{item}}} at the end of the expression [{{{item}}}] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@9:37 ("DropListEnterPredicate]="enter" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop()">
<div cdkDrag class="example-box">[ERROR ->]{{{item}}}</div>
</div>
</div> "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@9:37
Parser Error: Missing expected } at the end of the expression [{{{item}}}] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@9:37 ("DropListEnterPredicate]="enter" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop()">
<div cdkDrag class="example-box">[ERROR ->]{{{item}}}</div>
</div>
</div> "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@9:37
```

I've copied a simple stackblitz, in it I've duplicated the error by putting the triple braces around the `{{{item}}}`.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4kmtwp

I've tried `{ {{ item }} }`, `{{ '{' }} {{ item }} {{ '}' }}`, `&123;&123;&123; item &125;&125;&125;` but none of those render the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the line:

`<div cdkDrag class="example-box">{{{item}}}</div>`

to

`<div cdkDrag class="example-box" [innerHtml]="item"></div>`

As an additional note, if there are `class` names within the innerHtml that you need to style, you may need to set the `encapsulation` within the typescript file as `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

i.e. `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`